# Reporting Server throws an error for RunEmbeddedQuery method for XML data source

Tags: permissions, ssrs-2008, foxpro

This the scenario have. There's an SSRS server that has a report where the datasource is of type XML and it uses windows authentication, nothing else to it. Inside the report there's a dataset that uses that data source with this for a query "=Code.ReportUser.GetListOfItems()". This calls a method in the custom assembly that connects to the database and returns data in a string formated like this (angle brackets changed to curly for read

```
"<Query><XmlData><Items>" + xmlDocument.DocumentElement.InnerXml + "</Items></XmlData></Query>"
```

where sql datatable is written into the xmlDocument. If I go to the reporting server through an IE and run the report everything works as it should. The Problem occures when add this link to Zangle application which runs it as "IEHOST.app 'report's url'". I believe its a foxpro app that opens a browser object and report fails on the dataset that uses my xml data source. There's no question about url or reports correctness because it functions in a different environment.

This is the server error i get:

```
library!ReportServer_0-8!ca0!02/24/2012-10:18:45:: 
   Call to GetPermissionsAction(path to my report).
library!ReportServer_0-8!e68!02/24/2012-10:18:45:: 
   Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
library!ReportServer_0-8!e68!02/24/2012-10:18:45:: 
   Call to GetPropertiesAction(path to my report, PathBased).
library!ReportServer_0-8!10bc!02/24/2012-10:18:45:: 
   Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
library!ReportServer_0-8!e68!02/24/2012-10:18:45:: 
   Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
processing!ReportServer_0-8!10bc!02/24/2012-10:18:45:: 
   e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: , 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: 
   Error during processing of the CommandText expression of dataset ‘Items’.;
processing!ReportServer_0-8!10bc!02/24/2012-10:18:45:: 
   e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: , 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: 
   Cannot set the command text for dataset 'Items'. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: 
   Error during processing of the CommandText expression of dataset ‘Items’.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeDataSet.RunEmbeddedQuery(Boolean& readerExtensionsSupported, Boolean& readerFieldProperties, List`1 queryParams, Object[] paramValues)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

I'm not sure what this means exactly. Any thoughts? it looks like a permission issue but i don't understand where. I did try to change xml data source authentication from windows to none and then add my AD account as an execution user on the reporting server. This didnt' change anything still working from browser but from Zangle browser object. One more thing, server requires authentication and all the report regardless of the environment promt for login and successfully authenticate so my credentials seems to pass to the server and only my xml data source is throwing an error when launched from with Zangle. Please share your ideas. I'm a programmer but I'm not too server stuff savy and I'm new to SSRS. Thank you.

Comment: so far I narrowed the problem down to the query string. I hardcoded the query string to read <Query><XmlData><TestResult><Result>Success</Result></TestResult></XmlData></Query> with the same dataset of type XML and Windows integrated authentication (those are all the setting I have for it) and the report runs from within the foxpro internet browser app as intended. Looks like the issue is with the query been a method call to the assembly returning a string. May be missing some permissions somewhere for that type of call?

Comment: Further investigation revealed that the following line cause the issue using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString)). If I comment out everything inside using and return a hardcoded value eveyrthing works fine. I don't see any specific error thrown here it just fails. Same code work just fine through the reporting manger and reporting service just not through the IE object. i must be missing something in permissions. I do have [SqlClientPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)] set up for the class who's method contains that using directive.

Comment: Resolved. Turns out that foxpro app lowercases everything and the name of the sql server passed to the assembly doesn't match the name stored in the assembly. Silly :) So we'll be lowercase comparing everything from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Turns out that foxpro app lowercases everything and the name of the sql server passed to the assembly doesn't match the name stored in the assembly. Silly :) So we'll be lowercase comparing everything from now on.

Comment: to clarify the issue: based on the behavior that I observed when you access Globals!ReportFolder.Value you don't get back the value that you see in the Report Manger, you get the value that was part of the URL sent to the server. I think its an odd feature but that' s what I have on my SSRS server